# How to add box-shadow to a CSS div with display:table-row?

Tags: html, css, row, css-tables, box-shadow

How do you add `box-shadow` to a CSS table row?

Adding `box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888` to the element `table-row` in the code below does nothing and only works on the `table` element or the `table-cell` element:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}


<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 3
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ev36d1mh/

However, I need each `table-row` to have `box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888` and adding it to the `table-cell` creates a shadow between the two cells.  Eliminating the vertical shadowing is not an option.

So how can I add `box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888` to the entire row of a table?

Comment: display: table-row; is causing the shadow to not appear

Comment: @SherinMathew:  Yes, but I need to display `box-shadow` on the `table-row`.  Surely there is a way around that despite for some strange reason the `table-row` element not honoring the `box-shadow`.  I find it hard to believe that there is no way of adding `box-shadow` to a CSS table row.

Comment: Firefox shows the shadows, IE shows the shadow only on  the last row and chrome not at all .  table-row  is defaut display of tr, wich was in the beginning not really meant to be seen/styled but wrapping cells.  3 browsers with 3 different interpretation ...

Comment: @GCyrillus:  So it's impossible to add a `box-shadow` directly or indirectly to a CSS Table Row in a way that's compatible with all major browsers?

Comment: Unfortuatelly, this is what it looks alike :(

Comment: @GCyrillus:  Thank you for confirming.  Could you please add that as an answer so I can accept it so that others looking for this in the future know that it's not possible?  Thanks.

Comment: @GCyrillus Any reason for the re-open? Feel free to [join in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign) where we're discussing the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You actually cannot have this work through all majors browsers** without breaking the table-layout by resetting display to another value.

`display:table-row;` is the default display of `<tr>` table elements, wich where not supposed to be styled, just holding a row of cells (`td` / `th` ).
thead, tbody, tfoot would be the same, just containers to hold the table-layout.

Each browser will manage this their own way, firefox will accept it, IE will show only the last one where previous ones will lay underneath unseen and webkit won't show anything. The limit seems to draw a border depending (or not) on `border-collapse` value.

---

A turn around could be to used pseudo elements: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NNRVmd

```css
table, .table {
  padding:0;
  margin:1em;
  display:inline-table; /* for the show */
  border-spacing:2px;
  background:yellow;
  vertical-align:top;
}
td, .td {
  padding:1em;
  display:table-cell;
  background:lightgray;;
}
tr, .tr {
  display:table-row;
}

/* fix ? */
table, .table {
  position:relative;/* needed to set width to pseudos */
}
td:first-child:after,
.td:first-child:after{
  pointer-events:none;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  padding:1em;/* equals padding of td */
  margin-top:2px;
  /* do not use top and bottom */
  left:0;
  right:2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px;
}
td:last-child,
.td:last-child{
  box-shadow:6px 1px 2px -2px;/* finish the drawing on entire height of row */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Celll 1111</td>
  <td>Celll 222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cellll 33</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class=table>
  <div class=tr>
    <div class=td>Celll 1111 111</div>
  <div class=td>Celll 222</div>
  </div>
  <div class=tr>
    <div class=td>Cellll 33</div>
    <div class=td>Cell 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot chrome]

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question!  Marked as solved.

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl  added a turn around eventually in answer and here to play with :http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NNRVmd

Answer (score -2):

As @Sherin Matthew said remove `display: table-row;`

```
.table {
  display: table;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.row {
  //display: table-row;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}
```

I've commented out to show you which line - but you can delete it completely.

Comment: Thanks, but won't removing `display: table-row` not treat the HTML code as an actual table as it will be missing a critical element (the row)?  What are the downsides of not having a `table-row` as the row element of a CSS table?

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl That is the wrong question to ask. Really you should be asking "why do I want to use a table layout, and why am I not using an actual HTML table to do so?"

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl: Semantics aside, you actually can't not have a table-row in a CSS table (unless the table is completely empty). A CSS table box always consists of table-row boxes that in turn contain table-cell boxes. Removing the display: table-row just causes the .row element to be contained in an anonymous table-cell box in an anonymous table-row box within the .table element (and the .cell box to be in an anonymous table within the .row element's block box).

Answer (score -2):

try this way:

```
<div class="table">
 <div class="test">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 2
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="teste">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 3
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      CELL 4
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS put this in

```
.test{
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
  margin-bottom:2px;
 }
.teste{
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
 }
```

Comment: it still breaks the table-layout https://jsfiddle.net/ev36d1mh/3/

Comment: if you look in te inspector you will see that it is impossible to put margin or something arround an "table-row" or "table-cell" sorry but it is the only way i see

Comment: So it's impossible to achieve shadowing on an entire CSS Table Row directly or indirectly?  How could they have made something so trivial so difficult or impossible to achieve?

Comment: For me how he want to do is impossible the only way do do some kind of is the way I did it but it is not perfect that way I wouldn't do it