# Since box-shadow cannot be used on display:table-row elements, how can I mimic a table and use box-shadow on the pseudo-row elements?

Tags: html, css, row, css-tables, box-shadow

It's already been [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986760/how-to-add-box-shadow-to-a-css-div-with-displaytable-row) that it's not possible to add a `box-shadow` to a `display:table-row` element in a way that's compatible with all the major browsers.  For reasons that boggle my mind, a row cannot be styled as a group, which means you can't add a `box-shadow` to an entire row in a `display:table` and can only add it to the individual `display:table-cell` elements, which then creates vertical shadowing in-between cells which I don't want.

So how can I mimic a table whereby the width of the first pseudo-column of all the pseudo-rows of the pseudo-table are the same width as its longest element, and the second column is whatever width is left while adding `box-shadow` to the pseudo-row?

Right now I'm using `white-space: nowrap` and `width: 1px` on the first `display:table-cell` element of each `display:table-row` to ensure the left-most column of all rows are the width of the longest text in that column *regardless of the width of the screen*.

See example here:  https://jsfiddle.net/yupwh6uq/

That works great in terms of formatting the `display:table` and the columns, but it doesn't allow me to add `box-shadow` to the `display:table-row` elements.

**So how can I get the auto-column-width-adjusting table effect that I have now to display the info, but with the `box-shadow` on each pseudo-row in a way that's compatible with all major browsers using pure HTML/CSS?**

*P.S. I want to avoid using `display:flex;` as it will break the formatting on older browsers.*

Comment: did you take a look at http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NNRVmd and if you did, did it work good enough ?

Comment: @GCyrillus:  Thanks for that.  My fear with that solution is that somebody commented in the chat that it did not display the `box-shadow` well in FireFox, so now I'm looking for a solution that works in all major browsers.  Please let me know if you have any ideas, and thanks again for all your help.  You've been great!

Comment: else you may use display flex and use a flex value, this will give each cells a static % width ... http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NNRVmd

Comment: @GCyrillus:  The problem with `display:flex` is that it doesn't work with older Mobile browsers, for instance.  I know `box-shadow` doesn't work with older Mobile browsers either, but in that case, it simply won't display the shadowing.  However, if it doesn't understand `display:flex` then it will display the info all wrong, so that's not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: actually i haven't myself seen the problem in FF about the pseudo technic. **What you need will require javascript to set width of each columns element to make it bullet proof**. As said earlier, box-shadow is not cross browser avalaible for table-row / tr elements :(

Comment: @GCyrillus:  This is getting really tough!  Let me test your other solution a bit further to see how it does on older browsers.  Thanks again!

Comment: your fiddle updated  for test : https://jsfiddle.net/yupwh6uq/4/

Comment: @GCyrillus:  Many thanks!

Comment: Important questions that need to be answered here: **1)** If you want a table, why are you not using HTML table markup? **2)** If the last question and ensuing chat discussion told you it's not possible, why are you asking the same question again in a different way? You're asking for a perfect modern solution and support for older browsers; in reality you have to pick one: CSS-only solution or a more complex solution that supports older browsers. Look up the practice of "progressive enhancement" vs "graceful degradation" depending on your target audience.

Comment: @TylerH:  I don't necessarily need tables, but I do need the left cells of all results to be the same width, and I need that width to be the minimal amount needed such that no text in those first cells wraps, and I need the box-shadow, and I need this to work in the majority of browsers since part of my users use older browsers.  Since it's already shown that we can't achieve that with actual tables (although GCyrillus has a potential solution for that, albeit complicated), I'm asking if there's a way to achieve this *without* actual tables.  That's why I'm prepending everything with "pseudo".

Answer (score 0):

This can help

but it calculates with fix height of a row and need span in td (but it could not be a problem in the table)

http://codepen.io/michalkliment/pen/dWzwEG

(tested in safari (ipad/mac) / chrome / IE10 / firefox)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Celll 1111</span></td>
    <td><span>Celll 222</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Cellll 33</span></td>
    <td><span>Cell 4</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: [1]: http://codepen.io/michalkliment/pen/dWzwEG]